# Set milliseconds to hours in pandas up to 24 hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, time-series

I have the following DataFrame that summarizes the different cases I encounter in my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20120302, 20141017, 20150215], 
                   'time': [764, 17002, 110000517]}, dtype=np.uint64)
```

The numbers I see in the `df.time` column are unit-like, that add as the day goes by up to near `240000000` (for example, one of the last entries could be `235959281`). As you can suppose, they add up to 24 hours (one day).

I want to join both columns forming a `date_time` column that has `datetime64[ns]` format, so that I can further analyze with pandas.

**Problems:**

I'm able to join them (i.e. converting them to str) but I'm not getting the exact datetime format I want. When I join them, I get these values for example:

```
20120302764
2014101717002
20150215110000517
```

And I would like to get:

```
2012-03-02 00:00:00.764

2014-10-17 00:00:17.002

2015-02-15 11:00:00.517
```

**On my end:**

- Trying to convert directly with `pd.to_datetime()` fails, even providing the `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'` format.
- I'm able to join a `timedelta64[ns]` object with a `datetime64[ns]` to form the final column. However, the units converted with timedelta doesn't give the real hour, minute, second and millisecond.

**The question is:** ¿How can I get hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds from these "unit-like" quantities in a way such that I can then join it to a date column to form the full date_time?

Comment: "even providing the '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' format." because the format string should reflect the _current_ format. So something like `%Y%m%d` for the `date` column. Think about it as, you're telling the dataframe how to read the completely context-less series of number you're giving it.

Comment: @roganjosh True Rogan, the way to say is not the best. I perfectly understand what you mean: even providing the good format, there are moments where the format doesn't match and fails. Thanks for your quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert it all to string, so far as you were doing, use `zfill(9)` on the time column so they all have 9 digits with the missing zeros, concatenate it all together (the date and time), and use `pd.to_datetime` with the appropriate format:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str) + df.time.astype(str).str.zfill(9),
                                format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')

>>> df
       date       time                datetime
0  20120302        764 2012-03-02 00:00:00.764
1  20141017      17002 2014-10-17 00:00:17.002
2  20150215  110000517 2015-02-15 11:00:00.517
```

Comment: Wow, that is perfect. I was missing the way of filling the other zeroes so that the format matches. Very nice and very thankful for the quick response @sacul.  Resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20120302, 20141017, 20150215], 
                   'time': [764, 17002, 110000517]}, dtype=np.uint64)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')

df['combined'] = df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='ms')

print(df.head())
```

The issue with your attempt is that `format` is supposed to reflect the format of the *existing* data. You need to tell `pandas` how to read `20120302`. Then it's just a case of telling `Pandas` the units of time in [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and adding it to your datetime column.

Comment: This was what I was originally going to suggest, but it's not actually what OP is looking for: look at the last line of their expected output (`2015-02-15 11:00:00.517`), vs the output from your method (`2015-02-16 06:33:20.517`). It's not actually milliseconds represented in OP's input's `time` column

Comment: @sacul huh, good spot. Let me see if I can fix it and keep it distinct from your approach.

Comment: Good try. This has been one my earlier attempts, but, as @sacul suggests there are not ms, they are "unit-like" qtys and when you go up you don't get matched results.

Comment: Ultimately I don't think I can get around sacul's approach here but I'd kill for something that can avoid the string methods because they are _horribly_ inefficient wrappers around the python string types. I'll try for a bit longer.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the commitment Rogan. If you are able to provide a more efficient solution, I would be glad to accept it also. The real dfs of my problem are made of thousands of rows, so gains in efficiency when proccessing are very welcome.

Comment: @Ezarate, with thousands of rows, you should be OK (just tried with 30000, and it's done in a fraction of a second). If you start going into the hundreds of thousands of rows, it starts to get a bit slower with the string methods (about 3 seconds for 300000 rows)

Comment: But @roganjosh, I agree, string methods are nice to avoid if possible...

Comment: Thanks @sacul. It is a processing phase, so no need of a "critical" efficiency like a real time based app. However, if any of you can add more value to the answer, I would be delighted to learn from you.